# Cannot be converted to Context

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-adapter

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

import static android.icu.lang.UCharacter.GraphemeClusterBreak.T;
import static com.example.noah.app1.R.id.lstview;

public class Tab2 extends Fragment {

    ListView lstview;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2, container, false);

        lstview = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lstview);
        Tab2_list_view adapter = new Tab2_list_view(Tab2.this);

        lstview.setAdapter(adapter);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Here I get an error saying:
    Error:(27, 57) error: incompatible types: Tab2 cannot be converted to 
    Context

Tab2 is my MainActivity and Tab2_list_view has my code on for a ListView.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried replacing `Tab2.this` with `getActivity()` or `getContext()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of :

```
Tab2.this
```

you need to use the Activity Context. Use:

```
getActivity()
```

instead

Comment: `getActivity()` or `getContext()`?

Comment: as it is a Fragment...should use the `getActivity()`..

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 can you please help me to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50046175/fragment-cannot-be-converted-to-context-in-android